# Sort a list of file names by number at end

Tags: c++

I have a list of files :

```
foo10.tif
foo2.tif
...
foo102.tif
```

I would like to sort them according to number at end of file name.

Preferably using c++11 and lambdas.

Comment: this sounds like a job for regular expressions:  `(\d+)\.tif$`, http://rubular.com/r/wX7vDADWJ7

Comment: _`Preferably using c++11 and lambdas.`_ - any good reason for this?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is sometimes called a Natural Sort. There's some information and links in [this Jeff Atwood blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/). You can also search on SO for "natural sort".

Comment: @Blastfurnace the difference between natural sort and sorting by the number at the end, is that natural sort will sort aaa5 before bbb1, but sorting by the number will sort bbb1 first.  they are different sorts

Comment: @SamIam: You're right. I just saw the common "foo" prefix in the examples and made a possibly-wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works.  Let me know if you have any issues with it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vector<string> aFiles =
   {
      "foo10.tif",
      "foo2.tif",
      "foo102.tif",
   };

   sort(begin(aFiles), end(aFiles), [](const string& a, const string& b)
   {
      auto RemoveExtension = [](const string& s) -> string
      {
         string::size_type pos = s.find_last_of('.');
         if (pos != string::npos)
            return s.substr(0, pos);
         return s;
      };

      string partA = RemoveExtension(a), partB = RemoveExtension(b);
      if (partA.length() != partB.length())
         return partA.length() < partB.length();

      return partA < partB;
   } );

   for (string s : aFiles)
      cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've actually decided against using this natural ordering: going to use the standard ASCII ordering instead.